# Edit a strong param if it's present?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, strong-parameters

How can I conditionally edit a strong parameter? For example, I have the following which edits the strong parameter (country). It does something simple; changes it from long to short e.g. "United States" to "US".

```rb
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:user_id, :first_name, :last_name, :country, :currency).tap do |user_params|
    user_params[:country] = full_list_countries[params[:user][:country].to_sym]
  end
end
```

The problem is, it errors whenever `:country` isn't present.

How can I get the code to work whether `:country` is present or not?

Comment: What is the error that you're getting?

Comment: @Turtlean I figured it out. I was referring to `user_params` *inside* `user_params`. T'was a very bad idea (recursive function, CPU went to 100% almost immediately, fans too)

Comment: Haha, that makes sense. Ok, good for you then!

Answer (score 0):

Use `if params[:country].present?` to work out if the param is present and handle accordingly.

Note **don't** try to use `if user_params[:country].present?`, that will cause a recursive function and an infinite loop, which will cause your CPU to max out!

```rb
def user_params
  if params[:country].present?
    params.require(:user).permit(:user_id, :first_name, :last_name, :country, :currency).tap do |user_params|
      user_params[:country] = full_list_countries[params[:user][:country].to_sym]
    end
  else
    params.require(:user).permit(:user_id, :first_name, :last_name, :country, :currency)
  end
end
```

Comment: Should be `if params[:user] && params[:user][:country].present?`